# give back an error with Result type in Rust

Tags: rust, error-handling

I'm implementing a method that parse a sql table and it returns a collection of value. How can I have a return type of `Result<StructData, Error>`?

In the code I made I can only return the value (StructDATA) without returning the error. What am I doing wrong?

```
use clap::ErrorKind;
use libc::printf;
use libsqlite3_sys::Error;
use log::error;
use rusqlite::{Connection, Result};
use serde_xml_rs::expect;
use std::collections::*;
use std::error;
use std::f32::consts::E;
use std::io::{self, Read};

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Com_TO {
    id_type: i32,
    id_variable: i32,
    type_com: String,
    label_com: String,
}

pub struct Coms_TO {
    Com_TO_vec: Vec<Com_TO>, 
}

impl Coms_TO {
    pub fn new() -> Result<(Coms_TO, rusqlite::Error)> {
        let path = "XXX.db";
        let conn = Connection::open(path).expect("No possible connection");
        let mut query = conn
            .prepare("SELECT * FROM Coms_TO LIMIT 10")
            .expect("error");
        let id_iter = query
            .query_map([], |row| {
                Ok(Com_TO {
                    Id_type: row.get(0).expect("error Id_type"),
                    id_variable: row.get(1).expect("error Id_variable"),
                    type_com: row.get(2).expect("error type_com"),
                    label_com: row.get(3).expect("error label_com"),
                })
            })
            .expect("Mapping db failed");

        let id_iter_collection = id_iter.collect::<Result<Vec<Com_TO>>>();
        let id_iter_result = match id_iter_collection {
            Ok(id_iter_collection) => Coms_TO {
                Com_TO_vec: id_iter_collection,
            },
            Err(e) => panic!("{}", e),
        };
         Ok(id_iter_result)
    }
}
```

I tried to remove `Ok(id_iter_result)` and the `;` to give back the types present in the match but in this case I obtain a mismatch with an empty value as follows:

```
expected enum `Result<(Coms_TO, rusqlite::Error), rusqlite::Error>`
found unit type `()`
```

Comment: What is the problem? You're returning a `Result`.

Comment: Wait a second: there's no way you want a `Result<(X, Error)>`, you must have meant to put 
(`rusqlite::`) `Result<X>` which is the same as (`std::`) `Result<X, rusqlite::Error>`. Look at the difference in parentheses

Comment: What is the exact code you're trying that gives the error? And on which line does the error occur?

Answer (score 1):

Change the result type of `new` func to `Result<Coms_TO, rusqlite::Error>`? In your example you are returning tuple.

Comment: Either `std::result::Result<Coms_TO, rusqlite::Error>` or `rusqlite::Result<Coms_TO>`?